# Alfresco Share login error behind reverse proxy

Tags: authentication, apache2, alfresco, reverse-proxy, alfresco-share

I configure my Alfresco instance to be in a sub-URI (www.example.com/prefix/alfresco , www.example.com/prefix/alfresco/share) and all looks to be fine except that I can't log in Shared. The Catalina.out log this error:

> ERROR [alfresco.web.site] [http-apr-28080-exec-10]
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Possible CSRF attack noted when
>   asserting referer header
>   'http://www.example.com/prefix/alfresco/share/page/'. Request: POST
>   /prefix/alfresco/share/page/dologin, FAILED TEST: Assert referer POST
>   /prefix/alfresco/share/page/dologin :: referer:
>   'http://www.example.com/prefix/alfresco/share/page/' vs server &
>   context: http://10.140.8.144/ (string) or  (regexp)

Then the browser show me this page (www.example.com/prefix/alfresco/share/dologin):

> **Something's wrong with this page...**
>
> We may have hit an error or something might have been removed or
>   deleted, so check that the URL is correct.
>
> Alternatively you might not have permission to view the page (it could
>   be on a private site) or there could have been an internal error. Try
>   checking with your Alfresco administrator.
>
> If you're trying to get to your home page and it's no longer available
>   you should change it by clicking your name on the Alfresco toolbar.

I tried to deactivate the CSRF filter in share-config-custom.xml, but then I can't log and I don't have any message in the log, the login page show:

> Your authentication details have not been recognized or Alfresco may
>   not be available at this time.

My apache conf:

> ProxyPass           /prefix/alfresco
>   http://10.140.8.144:28080/prefix/alfresco ProxyPassReverse
>   /prefix/alfresco   http://10.140.8.144:28080/prefix/alfresco
>
> ProxyPass           /prefix/alfresco/share
>   http://10.140.8.144:28080/prefix/share ProxyPassReverse
>   /prefix/alfresco/share   http://10.140.8.144:28080/prefix/share

I could log before configure Alfresco for work in the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to deactivate the CSRF filter. If you changed the context path as described in the [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/deploy-contextpath.html) you need to make sure that the tomcat connector "knows" the outside context (hostname, port, context).

Either

- set proxyName and proxyPort
- set RemoteIpValve in tomcat server.xml and set required proxy header
  variables in apache (x-forwarded-for, x-forwarded-by,
  x-forwarded-proto)
- use proxy_ajp instead of proxy_http and define a ajp connector in
  tomcat